# Turning a Line Integral into a Contour one

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to compute an integral appearing in the article "On Determinants of Laplacians on Riemann Surfaces" of D'Hoker and Phong (page 541). It is as following. Fix $B\in \mathbb{R}_+$ and let $\lambda \in (0,1) \setminus\{\text{annoying points}\}$, then we want to show:

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{B-i\sin(\theta) -\lambda\sqrt{B^2+1}}{B-i\sin(\theta) -2\lambda\sqrt{B^2+1} +\lambda^2(B+i\sin(\theta))} d\theta = \frac{\pi}{1-\lambda}.$$

Quoting from their article:

> This integral can e viewed as a contour integral around the unit circle of a meromorphic function with a single pole inside, whose residue can be computed explicitly. A straightforward calculation then yields the value $\pi(1-\lambda)^{-1}$.

My **theorical problem** is that the integrand is not a $\pi$-periodic function. In specific its values at $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ disagree. How can I turn it into a contour integral? There doesn't seem to be any obvious and nice "completion" of the function to be used as a contour integral either. Am I missing something obvious?

My **second approach** has been to observe that the real part of the integrand is actually $\pi$-periodic, while the imaginary part is $\pi$-antiperiodic. Therefore I can just restrict to the real part and turn it into a contour integral (via the transformation $z:=e^{2i\theta}$). But this time the function has, besides $z=0$, another pole floating around in the unit circle, which make the computation quite messy.

An ideal answer to this question should address both the general philosophy of how to turn a line integral into a contour one, and the specific case in examination. But partial answers are obviously most welcome! Thanks!

**Edit** Numerical experiments with Mathematica show (or rather suggest) that the result claimed by the authors is actually correct.

Comment: I would start by finding the zero of the denominator. The authors claim that there exists only 1 zero, i.e. the integrand has only 1 pole. Once you find it, we can think about the contour to choose: to apply the residue theorem, the contour has to encircle the pole.

Comment: Note that, in order to find the zero in the denominator, both the real and imaginary parts are supposed to be =0. This means that you have to find a condition on $\lambda$ and $\theta$. For $\theta$ is easy: if $\lambda\neq \pm 1$, then $\theta=k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb Z$ kills the imaginary part. For the real part I got 2 solutions $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Comment: @Avitus Thanks for your response! Actually we are supposed to consider both $B$ and $\lambda$ as parameters. As you say the imaginary part of the denominator is killed by $\theta=k\pi$, but the real part is always $\neq0$ for any $\theta$ (excluding at most 2 "annoying" choices of $\lambda$, but we are allowed to do it). In specific the integrand, as a function of $\theta$, is non singular.

Comment: Problems arise if I try some "classic" transformation. $z:=e^{i\theta}$ gives rise to a function holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, but the integration path is not closed (it is the right semi-circle). For the transformation $z:=e^{2i\theta}$ the integration path is closed (the unit circle) but $i\sin(\theta)= \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{z} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}})$ which is not holomorphic on the whole unit circle. I think those are just two expressions of the same pathology, i.e. the original integrand is not $\pi$-periodic. What do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: If you cannot choose those values of $\lambda$ that kill the real part of the denominator, then the integrand is not meromorphic...and no poles, even if $\theta=k\pi$. As you correctly noted, such real part is independent of $\theta$. I thought that $B$ was fixed, though. In any case, even in this case you can use the residue theorem with $\int_{\gamma}f(B,\lambda,\theta)d\theta=0$ and $\gamma$ suitable path (for example upper half circle with radius $=\frac{\pi}{2}$, center 0 + real line from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$).

Comment: The real part is $\pi$-periodic, the imaginary part is odd and $2\pi$-periodic. Hence the integral is $\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \dotsb$. Then you get a standard integral over the unit circle with $\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2i}(z - 1/z)$. If I didn't make any mistakes, due to $d\theta = dz/(iz)$, you have two poles inside the unit disk, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, this agrees with my computation. I think I could try to compute the additional pole (and relative residue) by brute force, but it's gonna be long and not elegant. While the observation of the authors of the paper on the possibility of turning it into a contour integral with only one pole is very tantalizing. Do you think it is possible to do that? On the other hand, according to the suggestions of Avitus I was trying to play a bit with different contours to exclude this additional pole. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Well, you only have quadratics to factor, so finding the pole and corresponding residue isn't really difficult, it's somewhat messy, though, and one can easily make a mistake in the calculations. It could of course be that that is exactly what the authors meant; the transformation gives you a meromorphic function $g$ with exactly one pole in the unit disk, and then you multiply $g$ with $\frac1z$ which gives you a second pole of the actual integrand.